# Why is my gulpfile.js is not compiling to scripts.js when I run gulp scripts from the terminal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

Below is a copy of my gulpfile.js.  For some reason /util.js, /alert.js & push.js are not being compiled into my scripts.js file when I run "gulp scripts" from the terminal in VSCode.  I would appreciate an advice to help me sort out this problem. I'm new to gulpfile format, so I wouldn't be surprised if I've 
made a mistake somewhere

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

function scripts() {
    return gulp.src(
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/util.js',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/alert.js',
        'node_modules/var/push.js',
        'js/main.js',
        'js/other.js'
) 
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
}


// compile scss into css
function style() {
    // 1 where is scss file
    return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
    //  2 pass  that file through sass compiler
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError)) 
    // 3 where do iI have the compiled css? 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    // 4 stream changes to all browsers
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
      server: {
          baseDir: './'
 }  
 });
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', style);
    gulp.watch('*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}


exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.scripts = scripts;
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing several globs or paths to `gulp.src`, you should wrap them in an array:

```js
return gulp.src([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/util.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/alert.js',
    'node_modules/var/push.js',
    'js/main.js',
    'js/other.js'
])
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I forgot to include them.  Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference to the scripts being compiled into the scripts.js file.